# Error in SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, api, spring-boot

estoy tratando de hacer mi primera api con spring boot y mysql, hasta ahora hice funcionar el GET, y el DELETE, pero cuando uso el POST me sale el siguiente error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near** 'desc, level, place, year1, year2) values ('Lorem2 ipsum dolor sit amet, conse...' at line 1
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1098) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1046) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1371) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1031) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy99.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy99.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:637) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy102.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at com.test.markone.Service.EducationServiceImplement.save(EducationServiceImplement.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.test.markone.Service.EducationServiceImplement$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4da40354.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at com.test.markone.Service.EducationServiceImplement$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca3054fb.save() ~[classes/:na]
> at com.test.markone.Controller.EducationController.guardar(EducationController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

este es mi archivo controller:

```
package com.test.markone.Controller;

import com.test.markone.Model.Education;
import com.test.markone.Service.EducationService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EducationController {
    @Autowired
    private EducationService educationService;
    //Listado
    @GetMapping("/education")
    public List<Education> listar()
    {
        return educationService.findAll();
    }
    
    //Guardado
    
    @PostMapping("/education")
    public Education guardar(@RequestBody Education education)
    {
        return educationService.save(education);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/educaation/{id}")
    public Education getOneEducation(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        return educationService.findById(id);
    }
    
    //Modificar
    @PutMapping("/education/{id}")
    public Education modificar(@RequestBody Education education, @PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        Education educationActual= educationService.findById(id);
        educationActual.setYear1(education.getYear1());
        educationActual.setYear2(education.getYear2());
        educationActual.setLevel(education.getLevel());
        educationActual.setPlace(education.getPlace());
        educationActual.setDesc(education.getDesc());
        
        return educationService.save(educationActual);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/education/{id}")
    public void eliminar(@PathVariable Integer id)
    {
        educationService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

este es mi archivo dao:

```
package com.test.markone.Dao;

import com.test.markone.Model.Education;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface EducationDao extends CrudRepository<Education, Integer>{
    
}
```

este es mi model:

```
package com.test.markone.Model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Zz_education")
public class Education {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private Integer Id;
    @Column(name="Year1")
    private Integer Year1;
    @Column(name="Year2")
    private Integer Year2;
    @Column(name="Level")
    private String Level;
    @Column(name="Place")
    private String Place;
    @Column(name="Desc")
    private String Desc;

    public Integer getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public Integer getYear1() {
        return Year1;
    }

    public void setYear1(Integer Year1) {
        this.Year1 = Year1;
    }

    public Integer getYear2() {
        return Year2;
    }

    public void setYear2(Integer Year2) {
        this.Year2 = Year2;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return Level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String Level) {
        this.Level = Level;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return Place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String Place) {
        this.Place = Place;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return Desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String Desc) {
        this.Desc = Desc;
    }
    
}
```

este es mi archivo Service:

```
package com.test.markone.Service;

import com.test.markone.Model.Education;
import java.util.List;

public interface EducationService {
    public List<Education> findAll();
    public Education save(Education education);
    public Education findById(Integer id);
    public void delete(Integer id);
    
}
```

y este mi Service implement:

```
package com.test.markone.Service;

import com.test.markone.Dao.EducationDao;
import com.test.markone.Model.Education;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class EducationServiceImplement  implements EducationService{
    @Autowired
    private EducationDao educationDao;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Education> findAll()
    {
        return (List<Education>) educationDao.findAll();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public Education save(Education education)
    {
        return educationDao.save(education);
    }
    
    @Override
     @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Education findById(Integer id)
    {
        return educationDao.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    
    @Override
     @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void delete(Integer id)
    {
        educationDao.deleteById(id);
    }
    
}
```

por si las dudas adjunto la tabla creada:

```
CREATE TABLE `zz_education` (

  `Id` int(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,

  `Year1` year(4) NOT NULL,

  `Year2` year(4) NOT NULL,

  `Level` tinytext NOT NULL,

  `Place` text NOT NULL,

  `Desc` text NOT NULL

)
```

y esto es lo que me figura en Postman al ejecutar el POST:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
por lo que entiendo, hay un error en sintaxis, al menos eso dice la parte del error que resalte en negrita, pero no logro entender cual es el error, no se si alguien me podria ayudar, gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene toda la pinta de que tu campo `desc` está haciendo que todo falle porque **es una palabra reservada** de MariaDB, y ese conjunto no puede usarse como identificador (uno podríá usar comillas pa mencionar el campo y funcionaría, pero suena a mucho lío y problemas futuros de mantenimiento).

En caso de duda, mira siempre [la documentación](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/).

Cámbiale el nombre al campo y cambia los métodos asociados a ese campo, pa que usen el nuevo nombre y eso.

Comment: al final si era eso, lo que estaba sufriendo, pensar que cuando estaba escribiendo el campo desc no me di cuenta que estaba marcada de forma distinta, gracias!